# Load JS file into a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I Have an enpty array and a file with some array values:

`var myArray = [];`

file.json:

```
...
array[foo];
array[bar];
array[otherValue];
...
```

Whats the best way to load the file into a variable?

Comment: `file.json` isn't valid JSON— you'll need to make sure this is uses JSON array syntax (like: `["foo", "bar", "otherValue"]`) before Vincent's solution, below, will work. Even if this were normal Javascript, there is no assignment happening.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Node, just do `var myArray = require('path/to/json/file');`

Comment: No, i can't use Node, i only have available jQuery.

Comment: so where are you loading the file from?

Comment: This file is from root folder on my host.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the format of you json file of course.

Usign jQuery:

```
    var myArray = [];
    $.getJSON( "ajax/file.json", function( data ) {
        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            myArray.push( key +" "+ val );
        });
    });
```

Comment: `myArray` in this example is trapped in the callback's scope. You're apt to want something more like: `var myArray = []; $.getJSON('file.json', function (data) { $.each(data, function (key, value) { myArray.push(value) }) });` so that all values from the external JSON file are pushed as-is into the existing array.